# Font renders bigger in Chrome? Breaks absolute positioning

Tags: css, google-chrome, cross-browser

Chrome renders font bigger, why?

Our site relies on absolute position a lot and chrome just doesn't play nice.  IE & FF renders this spot on.

```
<div id="box"></div>
<h1 id="title">This is a title</h1>

#title {
    position: absolute;
    height: 120px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 195px;
    z-index:1000;
    font-family:"Arial";
}

#box {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    height: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 193px;
}
```

See:  http://jsfiddle.net/7yeLz/

Tried some reset.css, still doesn't work.  Any other workaround?

IE/FF:

[image: IE or Firefox]

Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

Comment: Looks OK to me. Doesn't appear to break anything.

Comment: would nowrap help? if the issue is that its wrapping not really the overall size of it

Comment: Try [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), it has a style to fix the `h1` element. Though Chrom applies a margin using the `:before` pseudo element so it may not fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly all browsers render font differently, varying slightly in character widths, spacing, weight, smoothing, etc.  If you need text to exactly fill the width of a container you could try something like this:

http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's no getting around it - browsers and OSes all [render fonts a little differently](http://css-tricks.com/font-rendering-differences-firefox-vs-ie-vs-safari/). You can fudge it with a negative letter spacing like `letter-spacing: -.01em;` or you can add `white-space: no-wrap;` to the H1.

Answer (score 0):

This is caused by Chrome's default `<h1>` styling,
Looking at the styles in Chrome's web console, they use the `-webkit-margin-before:0.67em;` style which you can fix like so:

```
h1 {
  -webkit-margin-before:0em ;    
  -webkit-margin-after:0em ;    
}
```

Solution: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yeLz/2/)

---

**Update:**

As FF rendered the text on two lines instead of one I though you were trying to achieve this look (sorry, I should have tested IE too to be sure.)

Looking at it in detail: A fix would be to change the `word-spacing` for chrome only to `-2px` (this also fixes FF for me but it already works for you of course).
Though from a design perspective it may be easier to simply add the extra 5px to the width, designing for the worst case browser to prevent wrapping in Chrome which is worse than extra space in FF & IE.

Comment: tried, same result as screenshot I just added above in the update.

Comment: @Henry, I get the same result as shown in your Chrome screenshot with my FF (v29.0.1), though IE displays it correctly(all on one line)